# Mongo db log rotate in shell script

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, unix

I am working on a shell script to rotate mongodb logs.
These are the log files.

```
 mongod.log.2018-10-03T07-39-59
 mongod.log



script.sh

rt=`mongo --host $host -u $user -p $pass --port $port --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )" | grep "ok"`

echo "$rt"

### compress newly rotated

for f in /logpath/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??;
do
        gzip "$f.gz" "$f"
        rm -f "$f"
done

### remove files older than x days
find /logpath/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??.gz -ctime +1 -delete
```

However i get this error
 ‘mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??’: No such file or directory

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory - there is no such file. What are you expecting `???..` to do? You're trying to perform operations on a file literally named `/logpath/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??.gz`

Answer (score 2):

Replacing

> gzip "$f.gz" "$f"

with

> gzip "$f"

removed the error.

Following script works without any error

```
rt=`mongo --host $host -u $user -p $pass --port $port --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )" | grep "ok"`

echo "$rt"

### compress newly rotated

for f in /logpath/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??;
do
        gzip "$f"
        rm -f "$f"
done

### remove files older than x days
find /logpath/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??.gz -ctime +1 -delete
```

Comment: One related question : How could I iterate over multiple paths saved as array. like : '/logpath/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??' , '/logpath_1/mongod.log.????-??-??T??-??-??' and so on.. @user6690412